# Can someone explain how to override the init method? I am trying to initialize square objects with a side integer value. I just don't know how?

Tags: objective-c

This is the code in the textbook, as much as I understand the gist of what the authors trying to accomplish, I don't understand the logic behind the code? an explanation would be most appreciative.

```
-(instancetype)initWithSide:(int)s
{  
 self = [super init];
 if (self){
 [self setSide: s];
}
 return self;
}
```

Why "self = [super init];" and when we "return self" what are we returning? Is it the integer value stored at "s" or on object?

Answer (score 0):

First, your `init` method calls `[super init]`.  This runs your superclass's initialization.  If you inherit from `NSObject`, there's not really anything for the superclass to do, but in the case of a more complex superclass like `UIViewController`, it might have to do a bunch of stuff.

Then, you assign the result of `[super init]` to `self` and check that `self != nil`.  If your superclass was unable to initialize the instance, it can return `nil`, and you'll pass that on to your caller.

Once your superclass has initialized the instance and you know it succeeded, you can do your own initialization.

Finally, you return `self` to your caller.  If `self` was set to `nil`, your caller can detect that you (or your superclass) failed to initialize.  If you return non-`nil`, your caller knows it has a valid object.

Comment: So when we return self, what are we returning?

Comment: You're returning the object that you just initialized, or nil if you couldn't initialize.